# Object given is not a Python function - gdal.RasterizeLayer

Tags: python, gdal, rasterization

I'm running into this error and I'm not quite sure what the error means. Novice here, operating out of jupyter environment, and trying to burn the vector layer of roads (road_lyr) into the raster road_ds.

```
gdal.RasterizeLayer( road_ds, [1], road_lyr, burn_values=[1], callback=gdal.TermProgress)
```

where my road_ds is

```
road_ds = gtiff_driver.Create('roads_prox.tif', in_band.XSize, in_band.YSize)
road_ds.SetProjection(in_ds.GetProjection())
road_ds.SetGeoTransform(in_ds.GetGeoTransform())
```

and road_lyr is

```
shp_ds = ogr.Open(folder)
road_lyr = shp_ds.GetLayerByName(roads_ln)
road_lyr.GetExtent()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-b8a413aa8f73> in <module>()
----> 1 gdal.RasterizeLayer( road_ds, [1], road_lyr, burn_values=[1], callback=gdal.TermProgress)
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py in RasterizeLayer(*args, **kwargs)
   1622 def RasterizeLayer(*args, **kwargs):
   1623     """RasterizeLayer(Dataset dataset, int bands, Layer layer, void * pfnTransformer=None, void * pTransformArg=None, int burn_values=0, char ** options=None, GDALProgressFunc callback=0, void * callback_data=None) -> int"""
-> 1624     return _gdal.RasterizeLayer(*args, **kwargs)
   1625 
   1626 def Polygonize(*args, **kwargs):
RuntimeError: Object given is not a Python function
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you looked to [Convert an OGR File to a Raster](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#convert-an-ogr-file-to-a-raster)?

Comment: Does it work with `callback=None`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have met the same error before, and I solve the problem after I defaulted to the parameter 'callback'.